# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have model it is have two MantToManyField, How I can sum or compain this two fields, there is number for each field, I want to have have result of sum this fields.

My model

```
class Video(models.Model):
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name='video_views')
    viewers_by_ip = models.ManyToManyField(UsersByIP, default='192.168.0.1', blank=True)
```

My view

```
    video_viewers_ip = video.viewers_by_ip.all()
    video_viewers = video.viewers.all()
    video_views = video_viewers_ip + video_viewers
```

Or how to get the result number in a new field

```
num_viewers = models.IntegerField('viewers_by_ip' + 'viewers')
```

Comment: do you want to sum the fields or simply combining or concatenating the two fields

Comment: Sum this field in wich the count of both be one number

Comment: then you must use a forloop on the queryset to get the items you want to sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just convert this

```
video_views = video_viewers_ip + video_viewers
```

to

```
video_views = len(list(chain(video_viewers_ip, video_viewers)))
```

and it's worked with me fine.

Answer (score 1):

in `views.py` use the annotate function to generate the result

```
video_views=Video.objects.all().annotate(vote_count=Count('viewers', distinct=True))
   .annotate(likes_count=Count('viewers_by_ip', distinct=True))
context={'video_views':video_views}
return render(request, template_to_display.html, context)
```